# Why are there so many map construction functions in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Novice question, but I don't really understand why there are so many operations for constructing maps in clojure.

You have `conj`, `assoc` and `merge`, but they seem to more or less do the same thing?

```
(assoc {:a 1 :b 2} :c 3)
(conj {:a 1 :b 2} {:c 3})
(merge {:a 1 :b 2} {:c 3})
```

What's really the difference and why are all these methods required when they do more or less the same thing?

Comment: There is also `(into {:a 1 :b 2} {:c 3})`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`assoc` and `conj` behave very differently for other data structures:

```
user=> (assoc [1 2 3 4] 1 5)
[1 5 3 4]
user=> (conj [1 2 3 4] 1 5)
[1 2 3 4 1 5]
```

If you are writing a function that can handle multiple kinds of collections, then your choice will make a big difference.

Treat `merge` as a maps-only function (its similar to `conj` for other collections).

My opinion:

- **assoc** - use when you are 'changing' existing key/value pairs
- **conj** - use when you are 'adding' new key/value pairs
- **merge** - use when you are combining two or more maps

Comment: `merge` takes an arbitary amount of maps and merges them, not just two.

Comment: `merge` is different from `conj` in its handling of `nil` (which gets converted to `{}`), regardless of the types of other arguments. Also, I have a different approach to the `assoc` vs. `conj` issue, but since I've posted a separate answer, I won't elaborate here. :-)

Comment: conj also works on arbitrary numbers of maps. 
user=> (conj {:a 1 :b 2} {:c 3} {:d 4})
{:d 4, :c 3, :a 1, :b 2}

Comment: how does `into` fit into this?

Answer (score 24):

Actually these functions behave quite differently when used with maps.

1. `conj`:

   Firstly, the `(conj {:a 1 :b 2} :c 3)` example from the question text does not work at all (neither with 1.1 nor with 1.2; `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown). There are just a handful of types which can be `conj`ed onto maps, namely two-element vectors, `clojure.lang.MapEntry`s (which are basically equivalent to two-element vectors) and maps.

   Note that `seq` of a map comprises a bunch of `MapEntry`s. Thus you can do e.g.

   ```
   (into a-map (filter a-predicate another-map))
   ```

   (note that `into` uses `conj` -- or `conj!`, when possible -- internally). Neither `merge` nor `assoc` allows you to do that.
2. `merge`:

   This is almost exactly equivalent to `conj`, but it replaces its `nil` arguments with `{}` -- empty hash maps -- and thus will return a map when the first "map" in the chain happens to be `nil`.

   ```
   (apply conj [nil {:a 1} {:b 2}])
   ; => ({:b 2} {:a 1}) ; clojure.lang.PersistentList
   (apply merge [nil {:a 1} {:b 2}])
   ; => {:a 1 :b 2} ; clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap
   ```

   Note there's nothing (except the docstring...) to stop the programmer from using `merge` with other collection types. If one does that, weirdness ensues; not recommended.
3. `assoc`:

   Again, the example from the question text -- `(assoc {:a 1 :b 2} {:c 3})` -- won't work; instead, it'll throw an `IllegalArgumentException`. `assoc` takes a map argument followed by an even number of arguments -- those in odd positions (let's say the map is at position 0) are keys, those at even positions are values. I find that I `assoc` things onto maps more often than I `conj`, though when I `conj`, `assoc` would feel cumbersome. ;-)
4. `merge-with`:

   For the sake of completeness, this is the final basic function dealing with maps. I find it extremely useful. It works as the docstring indicates; here's an example:

   ```
   (merge-with + {:a 1} {:a 3} {:a 5})
   ; => {:a 9}
   ```

   Note that if a map contains a "new" key, which hasn't occured in any of the maps to the left of it, the merging function will not be called. This is occasionally frustrating, but in 1.2 a clever `reify` can provide a map with non-`nil` "default values".

Comment: To illustrate the final point on `merge-with`, I've prepared the following Gist: http://gist.github.com/468332

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. As you saw I had a typing error and switched the second argument between conj and assoc.

Answer (score 8):

Since maps are such a ubiquitous data structure in Clojure, it makes sense to have multiple tools for manipulating them. The various different functions are all syntactically convenient in slightly different circumstances.

My personal take on the specific functions you mention :

- I use **assoc** to add a single value to a map given a key and value
- I use **merge** to combine two maps or add multiple new entries at once
- I don't generally use **conj** with maps at all as I associate it mentally with lists

Comment: I think the idiomatic approach would be to use whichever function matches the form in which the new items to be added to the map initially become available; if it's as maps, use `merge`, if as a bunch of keys and values not assembled in a collection, use `assoc` etc. What I really wanted to point out, though, is that `conj` is *the* universal Clojure data structure building function -- you can't really keep it in the list drawer.

Comment: @Michal maybe you are right - but for some reason I have a distrust of functions that do semantically very different things on different input types without warnings :-)

Comment: I would argue that `conj` **does** do semantically equivalent operations on different input types. ;)